# How to skip pre-chat page when use chatUserData method to pass field

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, pre-chat

I am working on Embedded Service SDK for Android.
I want to pass some field values to agent before chat, but I don't want to popup a pre-chat page, because all field value passed to agent is by default.
I used the following code to pass value, but it will pop up a pre-chat page. What I need is pass field value to agent without pop up pre-chat page. I can do this in IOS SDK , but in Android what should I do for this?

// Add user data and entities
chatConfigurationBuilder
.chatUserData(firstNameData, lastNameData)
.chatEntities(contactEntity)

// Build the chat configuration object
val chatConfiguration = chatConfigurationBuilder.build()

I want to skip the pre chat page and can pass default field value to agent

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but this is what worked for me:

You need to disablePreChatView from the ChatUIConfiguration.Builder()

```
ChatUIConfiguration.Builder().disablePreChatView(true)
```